# Is the inclusion $C^1[0,1]\subset C[0,1]$ compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compact-operators

I am working on this problem but i couldn't succeed .

Consider the space $C^1[0,1]$ with the norm $$\|f\|=\max \{\|f\|_{C[0,1]}, \|f'\|_{C[0,1]}\},$$

I don't know if the inclusion map is compact, but my friend said it is . How do i show that the inclusion map from $$(C^1[0,1],\| .\|) \to (C[0,1],\| .\|)$$ is compact  ?

Thanks .

Comment: Use Arzela-Ascoli.

Comment: @Martin : frankly , i am having trouble on how to proceed :( .

Comment: AA gives necessary and sufficient conditions for relative compactness in $C[0,1]$ (I assume you put the sup norm on it). Check that the image of the unit ball of $C^1[0,1]$ in $C[0,1]$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous, hence relatively compact in $C[0,1]$. For equicontinuity use the mean value theorem.

Comment: It would be nice if you tried to work out a solution along the lines I suggested and posted that as an answer.

Comment: Any progress? $ $

Comment: @Martin : I have been thinking how to apply MVT to get equicontinuity . Can u give me small clue ? Thanks .

Comment: If $\lVert f\rVert_{C^1} \leq 1$ then $|f'(\xi)| \leq 1$ for all $\xi \in [0,1]$. Deduce that $f$ is $1$-Lipschitz: if $x \lt y \in [0,1]$ then there is $\xi \in (x,y)$ such that $$|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(\xi)(y-x)| \leq \cdots$$

Comment: @Martin : now if i choose $|y-x| \le \epsilon $ , then it follows that $f \in C^1$ are equicontinuous . and it $|f\|_{C^1} \le 1$ , which gives the boundedness . And Arzela ascoli says that a subset is relatively compact iff its bounded and equicontinuous . It looks quite straight forward , is there anything that i need to take think about ?

Comment: Yes, it is quite straightforward, although your comment is not very clear. Please type this up carefully and put it into an answer box. You're on the right track.

Comment: @Martin : I will type it , please correct me wherever i am wrong . Thanks :)

Comment: Very good :) I'll check it later.

Comment: Is your answer coming?

Comment: @Martin I have written the answer, Please correct me :) Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will try to write an answer as @Martin suggested, Please correct me if i am wrong :

Here we use Arzela Ascoli : which says that  $M$ , a subset of Banach space $X=C[0,1]$ is relatively compact iff $M$ is bounded and equicontinuous .

Here , Let us take unit ball of $C^1[0,1]$ then $\|f\|_{C^1} \le 1$ for all $f \in B_1(0_{C^1[0,1]}) \subset  C^1[0,1]$ , hence for  such that $\frac {f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \le 1 $ ,   for all $f \in B_1(0_{C^1[0,1]})$

That is because for $f \in M=B_1{(0_{C_1[0,1]})}$ we have
$1\ge ∥f∥_ {C_1[0,1]}=\{\max{∥f∥_{C^0[0,1]},∥f′∥_{C^0[0,1]}} \}$
which implies that both $∥f∥_{C^0}≤1$ and $∥f′∥_{C^0}≤1$

Note the above follows from mean value theorem ie there exists $\zeta \in (x,y)$ , because $f$ is continuous , which $\implies$  $f(x)- f(y) = f'(\zeta) (x-y)$ 
But as we know that $|f'(\zeta) | \le 1$ from the definition of $C^1$ norm .

So we have a common lipschitz constant for all $f\in B_1(0_{C^1[0,1]} )$ , and we follow that for $|x-y| < \epsilon $ we get

which implies that $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon $ for all $f$ in the unit ball of $C^1[0,1]$

This gives me equicontinuity . ie restated "if a set of functions is bounded by common Lipschitz constant then the set is equicontinuous  " .

Now our task is to prove that unit ball of $C^1[0,1]$ is bounded in unit ball of $C[0,1]$ , that means $B_1(0_{C^1[0,1]}) \subset B_1{(0_{C[0,1]})}$
which seems clear while the $\|.\|_{C^1[0,1]} \ge \|.\|_C[0,1]$

It is useful to note that $T(f)(s) =\int_0^t f(s) ds$ is a compact operator , it follows directly from the above observation because $T$ maps from $C[0,1]$ to $C^1[0 1]$ . $T$ is continuous because $\|T\| \le \|f\|_{C[0,1]} \le \|f\|_{C^1[0,1]}$ , now composing $T$ with the inclusion map name it $i : C^1[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ which is compact . As we know that subspace of compact operators from Banach space to Banach space form a Ideal in the space of continuous operators . It follows that $T$ is compact.

If the proof is right then credit goes to Martin. 
Which gives us what we want . ( hopefully)

Comment: Thanks. A few comments, questions and corrections: 1) AA applies to $X = C[0,1]$, not an arbitrary Banach space. 2) what is the set $M$ to which you apply it? 3) how do you get "hence for $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there exists $\delta$ neighborhood"? 4) what is your common Lipschitz constant? 5) "Now our task is to prove that **the unit ball of** $C^1[0,1]$ is bounded in $C[0,1]$, that means $B_1(0_{C^1[0,1]}) \subset B_{\color{red}{1}}(0_{C[0,1]})$ which seems clear while the $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{C^1[0,1]} \color{red}{\geq} \lVert \cdot \rVert_{C[0,1]}$."

Comment: Really? But $C^1[0,1]$ is *unbounded* (as every respectable normed space...), the constant functions form a closed and unbounded set (both in $C^1$ and $C^0$), for example. It should really be the unit ball of $C^1[0,1]$ (as I tried to point out towards the end of 5))

Comment: @Martin : The common Lipschitz constant is $1$ , and $M$ is the set $C^1[0,1]$ , which is actually unit ball of $C^1[0,1]$ as u suggested . and for $\epsilon$ , we can get because $f$ is continuous and differentiable , and there exists $y\in [0,1]$ such that for a small nbd $\delta$ depending on $x$ , $|f(y)-f(z)|\le f'(x)|y-z|$ $y,z$ are in the nbd, isn't that true ?

Comment: Okay, now my question becomes: how do you know that the common Lipschitz constant is 1? *If* you know that (why exactly?) then the Lipschitz condition gives you the inequality $|f(y) - f(x)| \leq |y-x|$  for *all* $f \in M = B_1(0_{C^1})$ and *all* $x,y \in [0,1]$. No need to introduce $\varepsilon$'s and $\delta$'s.

Comment: @Martin : Ah , i got it i guess from ur hint "$M=B_1(0_{C^1})$ , if i take $f$ from unit ball then $\|f\|\le 1 $ which implies $\|f'\| \le 1$  , which gives $1$ as lipschitz constant .

Comment: Yes, if you meant to write "then $\lVert f \rVert_{C^1[0,1]} \leq 1$ which implies $\lVert f'\rVert_{C[0,1]}$." At this point I suggest that you collect the information from the comments so far and update/correct the answer, ok? It would probably be a good idea to write up the details of the proof of 1-Lipschitz continuity of all $f \in M$ (you may refer to the mean value theorem, of course).

Comment: @Martin:Yes , i meant that . Sure ! I will update and inform to you . Thanks a lot, meant a lot to me.

Comment: @Martin : A small question here . Using the above argument it looks to me that i can say that operator $T$ from $C[0,1]$ to $C[0,1]$ like $(Tf)(s)=\int_0^s f(t)dt$ is compact , because $T$ is essentially taking a continuous function to a differentiable function . and we can use the inclusion map as above and say that $T$ is compact .

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely correct (You can consider $T$ as a continuous operator $C[0,1] \to C^1[0,1]$ which you then compose with the compact inclusion $C^1[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ and composing a bounded operator with a compact operator gives a compact operator). Nice observation! :-)

Comment: I am still waiting for the update :)

Comment: So... What is going on?

Comment: @Martin : I am extremely sorry for the late reply . Can you go through my edit to ensure that its ok what i have written.

Comment: Yes, thank you. These are mostly cosmetic comments: 1) I would write this out: For $f \in M = B_{1}(0_{C^1[0,1]})$ we have $$1 \geq \lVert f\rVert_{C^1[0,1]} = \max\{\lVert f\rVert_{C^0[0,1]}, \lVert f'\rVert_{C^0[0,1]}\}$$ which implies that both $\lVert f\rVert_{C^0} \leq 1$ and $\lVert f' \rVert_{C^0} \leq 1$. The former inequality gives us boundedness of $M$ in $C[0,1]$ and the latter gives us equicontinuity by the mean value theorem... 2) You know $\zeta \in (x,y)$, not only $\zeta \in [0,1]$. 3) the proof is over before the last two paragraphs, which consist of additional information.

Comment: There are a number of typos and somewhat unfinished sentences, but that's not so important (correct them if you wish). I think you can accept this answer. +1 from me

Comment: @Martin : I added what you suggested :)

Comment: @Martin : I want to bother u again , suppose if i introduce $T_k(f)(t)=\int_0^t k(x,t)f(s)ds$ , where $k(x,y)$ is a continuous function from $[0,1]^2\to \mathbb C $ , i still would say from above that $T_k$ is compact , but i don't see a correct reason to put forward .